# Google Drive API throwing userRateLimitExceeded and then dailyLimitExceededUnreg

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, service-accounts

I'm using google drive API to fetch a few thousand documents. The credentials I'm using to connect are using the setServiceAccount and setServiceAccountPrivateKey.

When I start making requests - I'll receive the following after a short period of time:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "User Rate Limit Exceeded. Rate of requests for user exceed configured project quota. You may consider re-evaluating expected per-user traffic to the API and adjust project quota limits accordingly. You may monitor aggregate quota usage and adjust limits in the API Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas?project=<projid>",
    "reason" : "userRateLimitExceeded",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas?project=<projid>"
  }
```

After a few thousand items, I end up getting this error:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "usageLimits",
    "message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "reason" : "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "extendedHelp" : "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
  } ],
  "message" : "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
}
```

I visited the quotas page, and I have the following values (the UI wouldn't let me request to raise these quotas beyond these values - they were the max allowed):

```
Queries per day = 1,000,000,000
Queries per 100 seconds per user = 1,000
Queries per 100 seconds = 10,000
```

1) Is it possible to increase the quota beyond 10/sec for queries per user? Can I request a higher quota that 10/sec? How?

2) Why would I be hitting the the dailyLimitExceededUnreg errors? and how can I avoid it?

Some snippets of code:

```
Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountId)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(gdrivePrivateKey)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(ImmutableSet.of(DriveScopes.DRIVE,
                    DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER,
                    DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP))
                .setServiceAccountUser(serviceAccount.getServiceAccountUser())
                .build();
```

Sometimes retrieving the properties of the file:

```
File file = drive.files().get(itemid)
            .setFields("id, name, createdTime, modifiedTime, size, webContentLink")
            .execute();
```

or getting the file using one of `drive.files.export` or `drive.files.get`

Thanks,
Huw

Comment: please include your code

Comment: Added some to original post above - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is not really an answer but its to long to be a comment. I cant help you fix it but we might be able to mitigate the issue.

## userRateLimitExceeded

`userRateLimitExceeded` is flood protection your going to fast.  Your hitting a user quota which you cant change. Because you are using a service account everything is being lumped in under the same user. There is an optional pramater for all requests called quotauser if you add that to all your requests say a random number it sometimes will help by overriding the ip address.

I am not a Java dev but the library is very close to the .net library it might be something like this.

```
File file = drive.files().get(itemid)
            .setQuotaUser(randomstring)
            .setFields("id, name, createdTime, modifiedTime, size, webContentLink")
            .execute();
```

My question would be why are you doing a get on so many files that you would be hitting the speed quota.  The best fix would be to slow down make sure that you are making under 1000 requests per 100 seconds.  If you do get the error just stop for a few seconds and send the request again.

i wrote this a while ago its C# but it might help [google apis flood buster](https://www.daimto.com/google-apis-flood-buster/)

## Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.

Why you would be getting this error i dont know.  This error normally only shows up if you are sending a request without authentication but you are using a service account so that shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We were using the setQuotaUser in one place. I've added it to the rest. I got a few userRateLimitExceeded errors (I'm not currently throttling). After a short period of time - I'm back to getting the dailyLimitExceededUnreg error and I've no idea what's causing it.

The reason why we make a lot of get requests is because our software goes and gets each document and does some analysis on it - so we need to process every doc.

Comment: Your only option is going to be slow down.  Service accounts are single user your overloading that user.  The library itself is designed for exponential backoff so its doing what it can. You should just wait a few seconds and try again there is no way to really 100% remove this issue it depends a lot on the server you get when your request runs get a fast server and it can run through a lot of requests in 10 seconds then you are blocked for the remaining 90 seconds.

Comment: Thanks. We are going to slow down requests to see if that helps. Shame I seem to be more or less permanently stuck by the calls returning dailyLimitExceededUnreg. Managed a few (less than 100) successful calls yesterday afternoon before I got dailyLimitExceededUnreg and now I need to wait another day to try with the slower rate.

Comment: For the dailyLimitExceededUnreg error. It turns out that I was creating my own HttpRequestInitializer object so that I could increase the timeouts on some of my calls. Inside the initialize method, I wasn't calling the credential.initialize(request); method - which is a must to set up the request with the correct credentials.